# how to pass data to server which were fetched from database to text boxes, using ng-model,ng-value or any other method

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I fetch data from database and show them in text boxes using ng-value. Then I tried to bind text box's data using ng-model and pass them again to database in order to update database data.It works fine only if I changed values in both text boxes.But this method doesn't take values which were loaded using ng-value.

```js
$scope.showData = function(userName) {
  //$scope.userName=userName;
  console.log(userName);
  $http.get('/api/personalData/' + userName)
    .success(function(data) {
      if (data.error) {
        $scope.errorMsg = data.error;
        console.log("Data havn't retrieved");

      } else {
        $scope.personalData = data.personalData;
        console.log("Data retrieved successfully");
        console.log($scope.personalData);
      }

    });
};
$scope.editUser = function(userName) {
  $scope.personal = {
    'age': $scope.personal.age
  };
  //$scope.userName=userName;
  console.log("name:" + userName);
  $http.post('/api/editPersonalData/' + userName, $scope.personal)
    .success(function(data) {
      if (data.error) {
        $scope.errorMsg = data.error;
        console.log("Data havn't been sent");
      } else {
        console.log("Data sent successfully");
        console.log(data.personalData);
      }

    });
};


In Node.js file,

  app.get('/api/personalData/:userName', function(req, res) {
    var userName = req.params.userName;
    con.query("Select * from users where username=?", [userName], function(err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        res.json({
          personalData: result
        });
        console.log("successfully sent");
        console.log({
          personalData: result[0]
        });
      } else {
        res.json({
          error: "Error while performing query"
        });
        console.log("Error while performing query:" + err);
      }
    });
  });

app.post('/api/editPersonalData/:userName', function(req, res) {
  var userName = req.params.userName;


  var name = req.body.name;
  var age = req.body.age;
  console.log(userName + "," + name + "," + age);
  //console.log(name+","+age+","+userName);
  con.query("UPDATE users SET name=?,age=? WHERE username=?", [name, age, userName], function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      res.json({
        success: 'data updated'
      });
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      res.json({
        error: 'Error while performing query'
      });
      console.log("Error while performing query." + err);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="updateform">
  <div class="modal-body row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" ng-value="personalData[0].name" ng-model="personal.name" required autofocus/>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Age:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" ng-value="personalData[0].age" ng-model="personal.age" required autofocus/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="editUser(personalData[0].username)">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please provide the data that is being returned from your `$http.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do like that.

Try this instead:

```
$http.get(...)
  .success(function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
      // ...
    } else {
      $scope.personalData = data.personalData;
      // Bind default value for $scope.personal here
      $scope.personal = data.personalData[0];
    }
  });
```

and in the `HTML`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="personal.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="personal.age">
```